# How to share Session variables between controllers action in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I have a gridPanel in the first view. If i click a button in this view, the selected rows will be displayed in another view. I need to send information with these rows to the server so i can load some extra data in the action proper to the click button.
To perform that, i should use Session instead of TempData or ViewBag/ViewData because i don't know when the user will click the button. Please correct me if i'm mistaken.

My code is like that: In the client side with AJAX i call an action method to set the session variables:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({ url: 'Examples/SetSelectedStations', params: { selectedStations: stationsStr} });
```

in the `SetSelectedStations` controller i set the `Session["selected"]` so the controller action lokks like:

```
public ViewResult SetSelectedStations(string selectedStations)
        {
            Session["selected"] = selectedStations;
            return View();
        }
```

and i want to get `Session["selected"]` in an other controller called `ShowSelectedStations`:

```
public Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult ShowSelectedStations(string containerId)
        {
            string ss = Session["selected"] as string;
            // Here ss is null !!!       
        }
```

The problem is `Session["selected"]` is always null in the second controller!!!
Should i define Session["selected"] in other place? Is there a special configuration in the web.confg file?

Please notice that the sessionState in my web.config is like that:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="PgSessionStateStoreProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="PgSessionStateStoreProvider" type="NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider.PgSessionStateStoreProvider" enableExpiredSessionAutoDeletion="true" expiredSessionAutoDeletionInterval="1800000" enableSessionExpireCallback="false" connectionStringName="AspSQLProvider" applicationName="WebSite1" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

and the global.asax:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WIS_3_0
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Examples", action = "Ex3", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with the default session state provider?

Comment: @mxmissile i didnt try it with default session provider because i should use PgSessionStateStoreProvider

Comment: Just for troubleshooting purposes, you should try it. It will give you insight into weather it's related to custom provider or not. Easy to revert back, just comment/uncomment the `<sessionState>` node.

Comment: @mxmissile i get the some error with the default provider too

Comment: Good then its probably not the provider. Are you sure `selectedStations` is not null when you set the session variable?

Comment: @mxmissile yes i m sure

Comment: have you disabled the sessionState module? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.aspx

Can you post your global.asax?

Comment: Try also 

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

Comment: @theLaw i have added the glabal.asax file to my post. thanks

Comment: Try to add to global.asax the method: protected void Session_Start()
        {}